# Scala Lift - How to put project live

Tags: scala, lift, sbt

I'm coming to the end of a project and would like to know how to put the compiled version live.

I've been using sbt but this seems to be tied to the console, so when I close the session the app goes down.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you not create a `war` of your project and put into a Java app server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sbt package => yourname.war => copy yourname.war to tomcat/webapps

Comment: Thanks for the help, the app relies on comet, will this setup be ok?

Comment: You think about hot-deploy without breaking comet sessions? certainly not.